# ReactJS - Get selected value from dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

**Context:**
I have a form where two dropdowns menus are displayed. Each one call an API (Springboot) where I get data from User and Product. My Code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import {Button, Container, Form} from "react-bootstrap";
import useGetUsers from "../hooks/useGetUsers";
import useGetProducts from "../hooks/useGetProducts";



function AddProductToFavorite(){

    const {users, userError} = useGetUsers();
    const {products, productError} = useGetProducts();

    const[selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId] = useState(1);
    const[selectedProductId, setSelectedProductId] = useState(1);

    const onChangeUser = e => setSelectedUserId(e.target.value);
    const onChangeProduct = e => setSelectedProductId(e.target.value);


    if (!!userError) return <div>{userError}</div>;
    if (!users) return <div>Chargement des users...</div>;
    if (!!productError) return <div>{productError}</div>;
    if (!products) return <div>Chargement des produits...</div>;

    const addToFavorite = () => {
        axios
            .post("http://localhost:8080/api/user=" + selectedUserId + "&addProduct=" + selectedProductId, {})
            .then(function (response) {})
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group controlId="formUser">
                        <Form.Label>Liste des users</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="select">
                            {users.map(user => (
                                <option value={selectedUserId} onChange={onChangeUser} key={user.id}>{user.id} {user.firstname} {user.lastname.toUpperCase()}</option>
                            ))}

                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="formProduct">
                        <Form.Label>Liste des produits</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="select">
                            {products.map(product => (
                                <option value={selectedProductId} onChange={onChangeProduct} key={product.id}>{product.name} | Prix: {product.price}CHF</option>
                            ))}
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={addToFavorite}>
                        Ajouter aux favoris !
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
}

export default AddProductToFavorite;
```

**My Problem:**
When I click on the button "Ajouter aux favoris !". I want to send the ids from the User and the Product that are stored inside the select value with Axios post request.

I use a onChange to always have the selected choices from the dropdowns with 2 hooks. But it doesn't work. I have this error in the console when I click on the button:

```
Error: Request aborted
    createError 0.chunk.js:5056
    handleAbort 0.chunk.js:4543
    dispatchXhrRequest 0.chunk.js:4538
    xhrAdapter 0.chunk.js:4487
    dispatchRequest 0.chunk.js:5109
    promise callback*request 0.chunk.js:4896
    method 0.chunk.js:4921
    wrap 0.chunk.js:5451
    addToFavorite AddProductToFavorite.js:28
    callCallback 0.chunk.js:25038
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev 0.chunk.js:25087
    invokeGuardedCallback 0.chunk.js:25147
    invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError 0.chunk.js:25162
    executeDispatch 0.chunk.js:29397
    processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder 0.chunk.js:29429
    processDispatchQueue 0.chunk.js:29442
    dispatchEventsForPlugins 0.chunk.js:29453
    dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem 0.chunk.js:29664
    batchedEventUpdates$1 0.chunk.js:43349
    batchedEventUpdates 0.chunk.js:24836
    dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem 0.chunk.js:29663
    attemptToDispatchEvent 0.chunk.js:27146
    dispatchEvent 0.chunk.js:27064
    unstable_runWithPriority 0.chunk.js:58868
    runWithPriority$1 0.chunk.js:32444
    discreteUpdates$1 0.chunk.js:43366
    discreteUpdates 0.chunk.js:24848
    dispatchDiscreteEvent 0.chunk.js:27030
    addEventBubbleListener 0.chunk.js:27152
    addTrappedEventListener 0.chunk.js:29567
    listenToNativeEvent 0.chunk.js:29531
    listenToAllSupportedEvents 0.chunk.js:29482
    listenToAllSupportedEvents 0.chunk.js:29480
    createRootImpl 0.chunk.js:46772
    ReactDOMBlockingRoot 0.chunk.js:46724
    createLegacyRoot 0.chunk.js:46786
    legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer 0.chunk.js:46863
    legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer 0.chunk.js:46888
    render 0.chunk.js:46984
    js index.js:7
    js main.chunk.js:1103
    Webpack 7
        __webpack_require__
        fn
        1
        __webpack_require__
        checkDeferredModules
        webpackJsonpCallback
        <anonymous>
AddProductToFavorite.js:32
```

I know that the Post request is functional because I have tried with hard data.